# Most Efficient Method for Removing Rows with Two Conditions

Tags: excel, performance, vba, loops

What I'm trying to do is to remove rows in my spreadsheet that have values of 0 in two separate columns, as this indicates that there is no useful data in that row. While it is possible to use a `For loop` with `If/Then` conditions, I've found that this is incredibility slow because my dataset has ~51,000 rows andit will literally take hours, if not days, to run.

After some searching, I came across an alternate method, that I believe to be faster and am currently using:

```
Public Sub deleteRows()
     ' source: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=64364
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim RT As Date
    RT = Time

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For n = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If (Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 3).Value) = 0) And (Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 6).Value) = 0) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next n
    MsgBox Format(Time - RT, "hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

However, I ran a test with only 1000 cells, and it took 402 seconds to run, which indicates it would take 5.584 hours to run all of the data at the same rate.

Is there any way to speed up the process? Am I missing something obvious?

*Edit: This code is running as a subpart of another code, where ScreenUpdating = False is declared in the beginning of the code.

Comment: If you haven't done this elsewhere in your code, turn off `ScreenUpdating` before you start modifying the sheet. E.g., put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in front of the `For` loop. Then set that value `= True` just before the `MsgBox`.

Comment: @andyholaday I am using Application.ScreenUpdating = False in the beginning of the code, I should have specified that. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using autofilter:

```
Public Sub deleteRows()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim start

    start = Timer
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Set the range of interest, no need to include the entire data range
        Set rng = .Range("B2:F" & lastRow)
        rng.AutoFilter 2, 0 '~~> filter zeros on C column
        rng.AutoFilter 5, 0 '~~> filter zeros on F column
        '~~> Delete the entire row of the remaining visible cells
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    Debug.Print (Timer - start) * 1000 '~~> in ms
End Sub
```

Tried and tested on sample data (Cell B2:L52802).
The deleting took 11699.22 ms or roughly 11.7 seconds in my machine.
I think that's fast enough compared to your estimated 5 hours (1700 times faster to be specific).

Comment: @pnuts whoa... what machine do you got there!? btw, it is proportional to the number of matches I guess. When I tried it, there's at least 10k match of C and F being zeros. So that'll leave me 40k or so data. Of course the more data to delete, the more it takes Excel to process.

Comment: @L42 It took me a litte bit to get your code to run, but now it seems to be working like a charm. I had to change the crireria to ="=0.000)", but that seems to have fixed all issues. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One more thing; it still takes about 55 seconds to run as is. However if I remove the .Resize and .Offset sections in the EntireRow.Delete portion of the code, it runs in ~12 seconds. Is this normal?

Comment: @Redshift Yeah you can remove that. That's old habit of anticipating you have a header and resize for removing the extra range you've offset.

Answer (score 2):

Nah, it would actually take even longer. If you delete a row, every single row below it will be moved up individually, which obviously takes longer if there are more rows below the one you are deleting.

Here are a couple simple ways of doing it:

1. Using AutoFilter to filter for the undesired rows and then deleting the visible cells.
2. Using AutoFilter to filter for the rows you want to keep and copy those to a new workbook.
3. Sort the values first, so that all the undesired rows are at the bottom. You are allready deleting from the bottom up so you'd just have to insert a sort in front of your loop.

Comment: Well this really answer the question but it would be great if you've provided an example. Since I'm a fan of autofilter, I did post an approach that uses that.

Comment: @pnuts
Sorry for being unclear...my first post on stackoverflow^^
Redshift projected the execution time of looping through 1000 cells on to a larger sheet in a linear fashion and came up with 5.5 hours. It would take much longer then that due to the fact that execution time will extend exponentially as the sheet gets larger.
Because not only will you have to delete more rows, but deletion of every single row takes longer as you have to shift more rows.
Well, the Rows to keep/delete would be implicitly "selected" by filtering for value = 0 in Column 3 and 6..not quite sure if thats your meaning