# Increasingly Long Runtime for Macro

Tags: excel, performance, vba, optimization, time

My code works, but the problem is that it is taking an increasingly long time to run, with the time required to complete calculations increasing every time I use the macro. I've tried a variety of variations and modifications with the sytax, but as I'm pretty new to VBA, I havn't made a whole lot of progress. Here's the code I'm running (Note, it is running as a subset, and `ScreenUpdate = False`):

```
Public Sub deleteRows()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        '~~> Set the range of interest, no need to include the entire data range
            With .Range("B2:F" & lastRow)
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=0.000", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="=0.000", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With
        .Range("B1:F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With
    MsgBox Format(Time - start, "hh:mm:ss")

End Sub
```

This code basically removes zero-valued results from the data by deleting an entire row. Initially, it ran in about 12 seconds, but that soon became 55 second, which has progressed into increasing long runtimes, with a 'fast' now being in the 5 minuet range. Below is a spreadsheet with the recored runtimes and corresponding changes made:

```
Runtime Changes
6:30    None
7:50    None
5:37    Manually stepped through code
7:45    Run with .cells instead of .range("B1:B" & lastRow)
5:21    Run with .Range(B:B)  instead of .range("B1:B" & lastRow)
9:20    Run with application.calculation disabled/enabled, range unchanged
5:35    Run with application.enableEvents disabled/enabled, range unchanged
11:08   Run with application.enableEvents disabled/enabled, Range(B:B)
5:12    None
7:57    Run with Alternative code (old code)
5:45    Range changed to .Range(cells(2,2), Cells(lastRow,2)
10:25   Range changed to .Range(cells(2,2), Cells(lastRow,2), Application.Calculation Disabled/enabled
5:34    Range set to rngB  for .delete portion (range assigned to variable)
9:59    Range set as rng("B1:F" & lastRow)
5:58    Changed system settings for Excel to "High Priority", code reverted to original
9:41    Rerun of old code for comparison
9:26    Reun with change in old code criteria to "0.000"
0:10    Moved SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
5:15    Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
11:31   Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
11:38   Excel restart; Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
5:18    Excel restart; Rerun  SpecialCells……..Delete into 2nd With/End With
6:49    Removed 2nd with 'loop'; all data put into first with statement
```

I did some reasearh online, and it looks like this might be a known issue with Excel when working with large datasets, and as mine is ~51k rows, I can see how this might be the case. "...A macro that required several seconds to complete in an earlier version of Excel may require several minutes to complete in a later version of Excel. Alternatively, if you run a macro a second time, the macro may take twice as long to run as it did the first time." Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/199505

So my question is: Is there any way to make this run faster, like it initially did? Why is this happening?

Comment: PS: the 'old code' referenced in the runtime log can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068737/most-efficient-method-for-removing-rows-with-two-conditions

Comment: Is the formatting important? If not, maybe try using ADO to query out the cells you want (fields 2 & 5 <> 0.000) and pasting the recordset to a new sheet (or even then deleting this entire range and just pasting the queried results)?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue, although mine toook about 25s the first time and now about 90s for subsequent runs. The problem appears to be at the `.EntireRow.Delete` statement, that's what's taking all the time up.

Comment: @JohnBustos good suggestions. copy the filtered range, then delete the entire range, then paste.

Comment: Also an equally good suggestion @DavidZemens ... Stops the need to delete specific rows...

Comment: I'm trying it right now, not seeming to be any faster but I also have the cells filled with volatile `Rand()` function so I can see that the *calculation* is what's killing my run-time.  I will try again with that disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the result of several tests that I did by transfering the data to an array and then printing the array to the sheet. This is much more efficient than any copy/paste and also any sort of `.Delete` method especially when called in a loop.

These are all executing in about ONE SECOND, and "deleted" something like 35000+ rows each.

```
Start 8/6/2014 1:51:14 PM
Start copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:14 PM    lastRow=50000
End copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:14 PM for 12270 rows
Start print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:14 PM
End print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:14 PM
Finished 8/6/2014 1:51:14 PM


Start 8/6/2014 1:51:15 PM
Start copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:15 PM    lastRow=50000
End copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:15 PM for 12339 rows
Start print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:15 PM
End print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:15 PM
Finished 8/6/2014 1:51:15 PM


Start 8/6/2014 1:51:16 PM
Start copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:16 PM    lastRow=50000
End copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:16 PM for 12275 rows
Start print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:16 PM
End print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:16 PM
Finished 8/6/2014 1:51:16 PM


Start 8/6/2014 1:51:17 PM
Start copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:17 PM    lastRow=50000
End copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:17 PM for 12178 rows
Start print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:17 PM
End print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:17 PM
Finished 8/6/2014 1:51:17 PM


Start 8/6/2014 1:51:18 PM
Start copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:18 PM    lastRow=50000
End copy data to array 8/6/2014 1:51:18 PM for 12130 rows
Start print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:18 PM
End print to sheet 8/6/2014 1:51:18 PM
Finished 8/6/2014 1:51:18 PM
```

Here is the code I use to test it:

```
Sub TimerLoop()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 5
    deleteRows
Next
End Sub
```

Here is the modified function; note that I changed the filter parameters to ensure that I would be deleting a sufficiently large number of rows. Change back to your own criteria before running.

```
Public Sub deleteRows()
Range("B2:F50000").Formula = "=Round(Rand(),2)"

Dim values As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim visible As Range
Dim a As Range, r As Range
Dim nextRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim totalRows As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Debug.Print "Start " & Now()

    With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        'Use a range variable instaead of literal construction:
        Set rng = .Range("B2:F" & lastRow)

            With rng
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">0.500", Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">0.500", Operator:=xlFilterValues
            End With

            'Assign the values to an array:
            Debug.Print "Start copy data to array " & Now() & vbTab & "lastRow=" & lastRow

            Set visible = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            For Each a In visible.Areas
                For Each r In a.Rows
                totalRows = totalRows + 1
                'values(i) = r.Value
                Next
            Next

            ReDim values(1 To totalRows)

            For Each a In visible.Areas
                For Each r In a.Rows
                    i = i + 1
                    values(i) = r.Value
                Next
            Next


            'Turn off autofilter, clear the cells
            .AutoFilterMode = False
            rng.ClearContents
            Debug.Print "End copy data to array " & Now() & " for " & totalRows & " rows"
            'Put the values back in to the sheet, from the array
            Debug.Print "Start print to sheet " & Now()

            rng.Rows(1).Resize(totalRows).Value = _
                Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(values))

            Debug.Print "End print to sheet " & Now()

        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Rows("1:1").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With
Debug.Print "Finished " & Now() & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It's definitely running faster, but I'm still averaging 3:30 mins per run. I'm processing on a machine with a dual quadcore i7 and 32 gigs of ram, so I don't think I'm hardware limited... I do have to eliminate ~20k rows of data though, so could that explain the time difference?

Comment: When running your code, it took 7s for the first run, then 3:36, 3:04, 4:14, and the 5th run took 5:07. I'm stumped.

Comment: That's bizarre. I have I5 processor and pretty sure I don't have 32GB RAM either...  perhaps it is in the # of rows being deleted.  Does formatting matter or is it OK to only paste the *values*?

Comment: Copying and pasting values should work, as the data is constant, and there are no formulas.

Comment: Also, I should add that when I ran you code with the randomized data, it runs in less than a second. I think that indicates that the runtime is dependent on the rows that have to be deleted.

Comment: OK yes that makes sense in some of my tests it deletes very few rows.

Comment: see revision; my test is now "deleting" 30k rows in under 1 second.

Comment: Wow, this is blazing fast! One last question: is there a way to change the criteria to an OR condition? i.e. if field = 2 OR field = 5 has a value greater than 0, it needs to be retained.

Comment: Add another column of data to your table, and in that column use formula to sum the cells in column 2 and column 5 respectively, i.e., `=E3+F3`, then drag that formula down. Then do the AutoFilter on that column *instead* of on the other two?  That's probably the easiest way I can think of without turning this in to a completely new question.  As always, if this has answerd your problem, do consider upvoting or "accepting" it :)

Comment: There would be a fancier way to do that all in memory/arrays, too. but I am about ready to leave the office for the evening...

Comment: David, you have been more than helpful! Thanks so much! I figured out a way to make it work, so I think I'm set. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you have formulas on your spreadsheet I would add Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual at the beginning and Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic at the end just to make sure you're not recalculating every time you delete a row.